# Disable Oracle substitution parsing

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, plsql

I need to update a string (VARCHAR2) value in an Oracle database which contains Javascript code.

The update script contains the following string:

```
c===l&&p(a,b)
```

which when executed from "Oracle SQL Developer", triggers (on that line) the following popup:
[image: substitution popup]

Is there a way to disable the substitution parsing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this command to disable parsing for substitution variables for the session.

```
SET DEFINE OFF;
```

Enter this at the start of the query or operation.  This cannot be used with PL/SQL code blocks but the standard SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE allow it.

This [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2333994/851930) from 2010 shows this is a popular question!

Comment: It should be noted that this is a feature of SQL*Plus and is utilized by some graphical tools